# ActiveRecord 5.2.0.rc1 & Representable Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I updated the application and received an error with Representable:

> activerecord-5.2.0.rc1/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:24:in
>   `load': undefined method`new' for Representable::JSON:Module
>   (NoMethodError)

Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported here: https://github.com/trailblazer/representable/issues/224

It was a Rails 5.2 RC1 issue and has been fixed: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31855

Comment: I reported this issue)